# Max string length is 254 for KML?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, fields-attributes, kml, limitations

I have a network link KML which I'm downloading via Python script and then converting to shapefile in ArcGIS Desktop.  The problem I'm having is the max field length of 254.  It's truncating the PopupInfo field in my KML.  I need to convert all the data (longer than 254 characters!) to a feature layer or shapefile, so I'm seeking alternatives.  I have not been able to find a good answer here.

Comment: File geodatabase feature classes have unlimited text field lengths. Use them instead if you can.

Comment: Yup, dBase III+ maximum string length is 254. This is one of the many reasons to not use shapefiles.  Using ArcGIS, there really is no reason not to be using file geodatabase, though this comes dangerously close to an *opinion-based* question.

Comment: As already mentioned, the shapefile comments are spot on. Please confirm that's what your output is. If NOT shapefile, but fGDB, what software version are you using?